# Button with class name click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have button with class name of `sldprv` but when in document ready I checked that button with class clicked or not. Its not working and I am getting this error in Chrom,. and in Firefox it's not even working:

```
$(".sldprv").click(function(e) {
     alert('click');
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

**but with button Id it is working.**

I know there's too little basic I have missed but I can't see.

**[edited] To explain you bit more on this...**

I am working this code with  [Jquery Wizard](https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-wizard) that I am adding this class to the previous button only in the first step and removing that after follow the lines of code edited in the plug in js:

```
if ( state.isFirstStep || o.unidirectional ||
    state.step.hasClass( o.stepClasses.unidirectional ) ) {
    //TO DO: back to slide
    this.elements.backward.addClass("sldprv");
} else {
    
    this.elements.backward.removeAttr( disabled );
    this.elements.backward.removeClass("sldprv");
}
```

So that I can catch the previous button only at the first step and do my own animation

Hope you got the idea and what the issues is.

Comment: It's impossible to tell the reason with the information you're providing. Can you reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you check if your button class is really with the class "sldprv"? How is the html of your button?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fXb6s/

Comment: how many elements have that class

Comment: @jay: class="btn btn-inverse backward sldprv"

Comment: i believe its doing this because the element count might be too large or nonn-existent.. not too familiar with it. try adding context to your selector

Answer (score 1):

Look this: http://jsfiddle.net/fXb6s/1/. I just add jQuery as lib for it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $(".sldprv").click(function(e) {
             alert('click');
             e.preventDefault();
         });
});
```

Comment: yeah working separately. but not in the application i have only here this class is used.